# How to auto refresh webpage all controls in given time interval

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am looking for auto refresh the webpage and load the pervious data while loading the page.
current with button click I can refresh the data without any time limit , but I need it automatically with given time.

Comment: You should use ```ajax``` instead of loading the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Add this JavaScript to your page:

It refreshs the page every 5 Seconds

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
       window.location.reload(1);
    }, 5000);

</script>
```

Or if you like to click the button with jquery every 5 Seconds:

```
<button id="IdOfButton" >Click me </button>

<script>
    setInterval(function(){
       $('#IdOfButton').trigger('click');
    }, 5000);

</script>
```

Comment: Thank You, I want partially load the page.. actually I tryed with timer with update panel like <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <!-- your controls in panel -->
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>  with this it refersh page but what happen is it refersh only one <td> tage not onther one. please help in that.